# How to create a custom DSL in Ruby like YAML, Cucumber, Markdown, etc?

Tags: ruby, dsl

I currently have a Ruby-based DSL for creating slides that uses instance eval:

```
# slides.rb
slide {
  title 'Ruby Programming'
  subtitle 'A simple introduction'
  bullet 'First bullet'
  bullet 'Second bullet'
}

# implementation:
class DSL
  class Slide
    def title(title)
      @title = title
    end
    # ...etc...
  end

  def slide(&block)
    @slides << Slide.new.instance_eval(&block)
  end
end

dsl = DSL.new
dsl.instance_eval(File.read('slides.rb'))
```

Which results in something like this:

---

## Ruby Programming

### A simple introduction

- First bullet
- Second bullet

---

I would like to take this to the next level by creating a DSL that does not use Ruby syntax. Maybe something more like YAML or Markdown:

```
title: Ruby Programming
subtitle: A simple introduction
* First bullet
* Second bullet
```

How can I create a DSL/parser for this type of syntax?

Answer (score 3):

Someone already mentioned Parslet, but I thought I would demo how easy it is.

```
require 'parslet' 
require 'pp'

slides = <<EOS
  title: Ruby Programming
  subtitle: A simple introduction
  * First bullet
  * Second bullet
EOS

#Best to read the parser from the bottom up.

class SlidesParser < Parslet::Parser
    rule(:eol)          { str("\n") | any.absent? }
    rule(:ws?)          { match('[\s\t]').repeat(0) }
    rule(:rest_of_line) { ws? >> (str("\n").absent? >> any).repeat(1).as(:text) } 
    rule(:title)        { ws? >> str("title:")>> rest_of_line.as(:title) >> eol }
    rule(:subtitle)     { ws? >> str("subtitle:")>> rest_of_line.as(:subtitle) >> eol }
    rule(:bullet)       { ws? >> str("*") >> rest_of_line >> eol }
    rule(:bullet_list)  { bullet.repeat(1).as(:bullets) }
    rule(:slide)        { (title >> subtitle >> bullet_list).as(:slide) }
    root(:slide)
end

# Note: parts can be made optional by adding a ".maybe"  eg. => subtitle.maybe

result = SlidesParser.new.parse(slides)  
pp result
#{:slide=>
#  {:title=>{:text=>"Ruby Programming"@9},
#   :subtitle=>{:text=>"A simple introduction"@38},
#   :bullets=>[{:text=>"First bullet"@64}, {:text=>"Second bullet"@81}]}}
```

In Parslet, Parsers are only part of the job, as they just converting text into a ruby structure.

You then use tranforms to match/replace tree nodes to make the structure you want.

```
# You can do lots of things here.. I am just replacing the 'text' element with their value
# You can use transforms to build your custom AST from the raw ruby tree 
class SlidesTransform < Parslet::Transform
  rule(:text => simple(:str))        { str }
  # rule(
  #    :title => simple(:title), 
  #    :subtitle => simple(:subtitle), 
  #    :bullets => sequence(:bullets)) { Slide.new(title, subtitle, bullets) }
end

pp SlidesTransform.new.apply(result)
#{:slide=>
#  {:title=>"Ruby Programming"@9,
#   :subtitle=>"A simple introduction"@38,
#   :bullets=>["First bullet"@64, "Second bullet"@81]}}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe Cucumber [uses Ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/) for its parser, here's a [decent looking intro to it](http://thingsaaronmade.com/blog/a-simple-intro-to-writing-a-lexer-with-ragel.html) using Ruby...

[Treetop](http://treetop.rubyforge.org) is also pretty common, along with [Parslet](http://kschiess.github.io/parslet/).

[ANTLR](http://antlr.ohboyohboyohboy.org), Rex and Racc...  All kinds of ways to handle external DSLs.

[Eloquent Ruby](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321584104) has a chapter on external DSL creation, from basic string parsing and regexes to using Treetop...

Comment: I started looking into Treetop before asking this question, but there's a lot of jargon and it's difficult to understand what's going on. Parslet looks like it has a better tutorial, so I'll check that one out. I own the Eloquent Ruby book, but didn't remember that it had a Treetop example. I'll have to check it out again.

Comment: Hah, yeah, be ready for jargon overload if this is your first foray into lexing/parsing.  The upside is it's really cool when you get something working!

Answer (score 2):

You can do rudimentary parsing with regexp. Something like this:

```
slides = <<EOS
  title: Ruby Programming
  subtitle: A simple introduction
  * First bullet
  * Second bullet
EOS

regexp = %r{
  (title:\s+)(?<title>[^\n]*)|
  (subtitle:\s+)(?<subtitle>[^\n]*)|
  (\*\s+)(?<bullet>[^\n]*)
}x

tags = {
  'title' => 'h1',
  'subtitle' => 'h2',
  'bullet' => 'li'
}

fUL = false
slides.lines.each {|line|
  md = line.match(regexp)
  md.names.select{|k| md[k]}.each {|k|
    puts '<ul>' or fUL = true if k == 'bullet' && !fUL
    puts '</ul>' or fUL = false if k != 'bullet' && fUL
    puts "<#{tags[k]}>#{md[k]}</#{tags[k]}>"
  }
}
puts '</ul>' if fUL
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe its worth a look at some current open-sourced implementations.

But I have to ask - why are you making your own? why dont you use one which is already available? [TOML](https://github.com/mojombo/toml) is great.

Ruby parser implementation: https://github.com/jm/toml